# configurar un tema en extJS

Tags: json, extjs

buenas noches srs. estoy haciendo una app en extJS 6 con sencha CMD6 y me gustaria utilizar el theme crisp pero me da error el compilador cuando ejecuto el build o el app wath

actualmente tiene es un neptune clasico que no me gusta el app
` /**
     * The Sencha Framework for this application: "ext" or "touch".
     */
    "framework": "ext",

```
/**
 * The toolkit to use. Select either "classic" or "modern".
 */

"toolkit": "modern",


/*
 * The name of the theme for this application.

*/


"theme": "theme-neptune",
```

` pero si coloco theme-crisp me da un error en consola que no encuentra la libreria para este tema y tambien intente asi:

```
    "builds": {
    "classic": {
        "toolkit": "classic",

        "theme": "theme-crisp",

        "sass": {
            // "save": "classic/sass/save.scss"
        }
    },

    "modern": {
        "toolkit": "modern",

        "theme": "theme-crisp",

        "sass": {
            // "save": "modern/sass/save.scss"
        }
    }
},
```

y tampoco me funciono y se ve con ese neptune feo alguien que porfavor me eche un mano muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no existe el *theme-crisp* dentro del toolkit modern, te paso los que tenes disponibles

**Modern Toolkit**

theme-material - Material Design theme.
theme-ios - iOS Theme.
theme-triton - Modern flat, borderless theme.
theme-neptune - Modern borderless theme.

**Classic Toolkit**

theme-triton - Modern theme using font-icons. Extends "theme-neptune".
theme-crisp - Minimalistic Theme. Extends "theme-neptune".
theme-crisp-touch - Crisp-Based Touch Theme. Extends "theme-crisp".
theme-neptune - Modern borderless theme.
theme-neptune-touch - Neptune-Based Touch Theme. Extends "theme-neptune".
theme-classic - The classic blue Ext JS theme.
theme-gray - Gray theme. Extends "theme-classic".